# In extjs4 how to disable tpl's radiobuttons

Tags: extjs4, radio-button

I am working in extjs4. I have tpl view with radio buttons as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsReview',
{
        extend:'Ext.view.View',
        id:'qbqnsViewId',
        alias:'widget.QbqnsReviewView',
        title:'Review of paper',
        store:'qb.QbqnsStore',
     config:
        {
            tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
                '<div id="main">'+
                '</br>'+

                '<id="q">{#} :- {question}'+

                '<tpl for="options">'+
                    '<tpl if="parent.Correctoption==optionId">'+
                    '<p style="color:Green"><input type="radio"  disable="true" name="{option}">{option}</p>'+
                    '<tpl elseif="parent.UsersOption==optionId">'+
                    '<p style="color:Red"><input type="radio" name="{option}">{option}</p>'+
                    '<tpl else>'+
                    '<p><input type="radio" name="{optionId}" value="{option}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
                    '</tpl>'+  
                '</tpl>'+   
 '<p>---------------------------------------------------------</p>'+
                '</div>'+
        '</tpl>',

         itemSelector:'div.main'
        }
```

I want to make this view as read only.i.e. i want make these radio buttons as disable. So how to perform it in extjs4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper html for a disabled radio button would be this:

```
<input type="radio" disabled="disabled" name="{option}" />
```

Your code has `disable="true"`.